# wxWidgets/GTK: How do I isolate wxWidgets's main loop from another main loop?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, gtk3

I'm developing an plugin for [Mupen64Plus](https://mupen64plus.org). While the Mupen64Plus core library doesn't create a GUI, a separate component (called the frontend) does.

I wrote the frontend in C# using [Eto](https://github.com/picoe/Eto), which works similarly to wxWidgets by using the native toolkit on each platform. This means it also runs on GTK3. Interestingly, it seems that when I call `ExitMainLoop` from wxWidgets, it also seems to take down the frontend's main loop along with it.

So here's my question: How can I isolate wxWidgets's main loop from my frontend's main loop? Under the hood, both will call `gtk_main()` to start their event loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run your main loop in a separate thread, this would be the simplest solution. Running two even loops in the same thread is possible too, but requires some cooperation between them, e.g. manually dispatching events for the other loop from the first one.

Comment: Trying this on GTK proves fruitless, as the result is exactly what I mentioned earlier.